# While Loop displaying even numbers in Python

Tags: python

I am unable to solve this.

Problem Statement:-
Make use of while loop and print all positive even numbers smaller than or equal to the number given by the user

e.g.:-

```
User Input: 6
Output: 2, 4, 6
```

I have tried this but the code is running into an infinite loop.

```
num = int(input("Please enter an even number: "))
i = 0 
while num >= i :
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num)
        i = num + 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: If the number the user provided is an odd number, your if statement will never be run, and thus never increments i.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? It is a critical skill to understand what your program is doing.

Comment: `for i in range(num + 1): if ..: print(..)` — No need to manually increment `i` and thus produce such bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a while loop here, just use a for loop:

```
num = int(input("Please enter an even number: "))

for nr in range(0, num, 2):
    print(nr)
```